# how to upload multiple images using block in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

```
 $fieldset->addField(
            'image',
            'image',
            [
                'name' => 'image[]',
                'multiple' => true,
                'label' => __('Customer Images'),
                'title' => __('Customer Images'),
            ]
        );
```

Comment: above code working??